# How can I embed UIViews (or, more specifically, UITextAreas) programmatically in-line with Text?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uitextfield

For reasons of reusability, I'm interested in finding a way to programmatically add text and custom UITextFields to a view in an efficient manner, similar to how you can combine strings using NSString's stringWithFormat: and then assign the result to a UILabel's text attribute. Ideally, with 2-3 statements I could write text and include my UITextField Objects in a string, and get an automatically text-wrapped, nicely formatted UIView that I can embed directly into my view. Basically, it would function like a UILabel with the ability to add UIView objects. For an example of the output this image would be a combination of both text and underlined UITextFields:

[image]
If this exists, it would allow me to reuse a single UITableViewCell subclass rather than having 5-6 xibs and 3-4 subclasses. I've searched about 2 hours with no real luck for a pre-existing solution, so has anyone ever encountered this problem before and used or released a library to handle this, or is there a simple solution I'm overlooking?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use CSLinearLayoutView (https://github.com/scalessec/CSLinearLayoutView)
and create a class

```
@implementation LabledView

+ (UIView*)create :(CGRect) frame view:(UIView*) view labelTitle:(NSString*)labelTitle viewLinearLayoutMakePadding :(CSLinearLayoutItemPadding)viewLinearLayoutMakePadding labelLinearLayoutMakePadding :(CSLinearLayoutItemPadding)labelLinearLayoutMakePadding font:(UIFont*)font textColor:(UIColor*)textColor
{
    CSLinearLayoutView *container = [[CSLinearLayoutView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    container.orientation = CSLinearLayoutViewOrientationHorizontal;

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.textColor = textColor;
    [label setText:labelTitle];
    [label setFont:font];
    [label sizeToFit];

    CSLinearLayoutItem *itemLabel = [CSLinearLayoutItem layoutItemForView:label];
    itemLabel.padding = labelLinearLayoutMakePadding;

    CSLinearLayoutItem *itemView = [CSLinearLayoutItem layoutItemForView:view];
    itemView.padding = viewLinearLayoutMakePadding;

    [container addItem:itemLabel];
    [container addItem:itemView];
    return container;
}
```

example :

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 260, 40)];

UIView *customView = [LabledView create:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 40) view:textField 
labelTitle:@"your label" viewLinearLayoutMakePadding:CSLinearLayoutMakePadding(0, 10, 0, 0) 
labelLinearLayoutMakePadding:CSLinearLayoutMakePadding(10, 0, 0, 0)
 font:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12] textColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Comment: Almost exactly what I was looking for! The only thing that would make this library better is if could automatically wrap strings between two lines, but when you throw objects into the mix that starts getting pretty complicated. I'll compensate by just using an array representing lines. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can underline specific ranges of a string with NSAtttibutedString.  You can setAttributedString to UILabel in ios6... So that's the way I'd do it, then it can indeed be in a single label with the desired parts underlined (or in a different font/colour/etc) only. Be careful when you look into attributed string, it's attributes dictionary uses different keys for working with UIKit (these are the ones you need here) to what it uses with CoreText

Comment: I spent a lot of time looking at NSAttributedString to see if I could use and/or modify it to do what I want since it could handle automatically formatting it, and firing off selectors based on character ranges. I found that if I used NSAttributedString I could do the underlining but then I wouldn't be able to add interactive UITextFields to the text at all, and it would be an excessive, very anti-DRY effort to duplicate the features I need from UITextField manually.